# Getting and sending HTTP request with Python

Tags: python, http, google-app-engine

I'm making the jump from PHP and MySQL to Python and Google App Engine, and it's a bit different from what I'm used to. For now, I'm just trying to find out the basics of a server request.

From my client (an iPhone), I send a dictionary in JSON format with a HTTP request (it's set as the POST value).

1. How do I get this dictionary in Python? In PHP, I would do:
   `$dictionary=json_decode(stripslashes($_POST["dictionary"]));`

   What's the Python equivalent?

Then say I run some queries, and I want to send a JSON string back to my client as a response. How would I do this in Python? Is it just `self.response.out.write()`? What would I put in the parenthesis to send a JSON representation of the Python dictionary?

Comment: Make sure to check [Requests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests) library which seems to be the best way to send HTTP requests in Python currently.

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost: this question has nothing to do with using Python to request something from another server.

Comment: @Wooble Really? How do you understand "sending HTTP request in Python" in the title, then?

Comment: Did you read the question? The request is being sent from an iPhone application to a python script running on App Engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`json`](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html).

- `json.loads()` is the equivalent of PHP's `json_decode()`
- `json.dumps()` is the equivalent of PHP's `json_encode()`

Comment: And what's the equivalent of $_POST["dictionary"]?

Comment: Is it `self.request.get('dictionary')`?

Comment: Actually, it's more like `self.request.POST['dictionary']`. `self.request.get` is a function that fetches the value from either query string parameters or request body. (That is to say, it'll work, but it will happily return a query string value instead, if there is one)

Comment: Granted, if you're relying on differentiating between the two, you may have problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you are starting to write in Python after PHP, [php2python site](http://www.php2python.com/) will help you translate some php functions to python ones.